# in revit , dynamo how can i use python to get all wires and the elements connected to them

Tags: python, revit-api

i need to get all wires and the elemnent connected to them
Can somebody write a python script in duynamo to acomplish this?

i have acomplished nothing of this, i dont know how make this happend

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this using a [filtered element collector](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2023/263cf06b-98be-6f91-c4da-fb47d01688f3.htm). The Building Coder provides numerous examples with lots sample code in the topic group [5.9 on Retrieving Elements Using `FilteredElementCollector`](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.9).

If you are just getting started with the Revit API, check out the [Getting Started material](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#2) first. There are lots of Dynamo tutorials available as well. Here are some pointers on getting started with that: [Learning Python and Dynamo](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2021/02/addin-file-learning-python-and-ifcjs.html#3).